# Why isn't my Redis cache working in my Spring-Boot/Spring-Data application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-data

I'm adding a local Redis cache to my Spring-Boot/Spring-Data application. As far as I can tell, the cache should work if I do three things:

1. I've annotated my application class with @Cachable:

   ```
   @Cacheable(cacheNames = "menuItems")
   @SpringBootApplication
   @ComponentScan(basePackages = { ... })
   public class OpenAPI2SpringBoot implements CommandLineRunner { ... }
   ```
2. I've added properties to application.properties:

   ```
   #Redis cache
   spring.cache.type=redis
   spring.redis.host=127.0.0.1
   spring.redis.port=6379
   ```

I've annotated my repository calls inside a wrapper class

```
@Component
public class MenuItemRepository {
  static final String MENU_ITEM_CACHE = "menuItems";
  // this is declared like this:
  // class MenuItemUncachedRepository extends JpaRepository<MenuItem, Integer>
  private final MenuItemUncachedRepository menuItemRepository; // actual repo.
  
  @Autowired
  public MenuItemRepository(MenuItemUncachedRepository repository) {
    menuItemRepository = repository;
  }
  
  public MenuItem findOne(Integer id) {
    return menuItemRepository.findOne(id);
  }
  
  @Cacheable(cacheNames = MENU_ITEM_CACHE, key = "all")
  public List<MenuItem> findAll() {
    return menuItemRepository.findAll();
  }

  @CacheEvict(cacheNames = MenuItemRepository.MENU_ITEM_CACHE)
  public <M extends MenuItem> M save(M menuItem) {
    return menuItemRepository.save(menuItem);
  }
}
```

My actual repository is not public, so all calls need to go through the annotated wrapper class. Logging confirms the annotated methods are getting called.

So I launched my cache monitor like this: `redis-cli MONITOR` I'm getting data from the application, so I know the repository works. I should see my value get set in the monitor when I execute the findAll() method, but nothing happens. I'm new to Redis, so it's probably something small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your `OpenAPI2SpringBoot` class. You don't need `@Cacheable` annotation over it, you need `@EnableCaching`